# php mssql database query not working

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I need some help.  I am writing a small program to retrieve data from mssql database using php.  When I write the query on sql management studio I get a result, but when I run the same query within php I dont get any results.

the following is on init.php.  This is file containing the database connection strings

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
$serverName = "SUPERMAN";

$connectionInfo = array('Database'=>'Eque', "UID"=>"develop", "PWD"=>"develop");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);


if($conn) {
    "Connection established.<br />";
}else {
    "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

the following is test page where the data is supposed to be displayed:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'scripts/init.php';

$query = "SELECT a.ID AS ApnID, b.Surname, b.Initials, b.Cell, b.Email, 
                            a.Deadline, a.NotifyEmail, a.NotifySMS, c.Name, a.RecvDate,a.Barcode
                        FROM dbo.Apn a
                        INNER JOIN dbo.Apt b ON a.AptID = b.ID
                        INNER JOIN dbo.Status c ON a.StatusID = c.ID";

//$params = array($id, $name);      
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query);

$record = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
                {
                    echo $record['Surname'];
                    echo '<br />';
                    echo $record['Initials']; 
                    echo '<br />';
                }



?>
```

I connects properly to the database, therefore I think the issue lies on the test page.  Please Assist!

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: One thing I've noticed in my testing is that the driver will fall over badly when it encounters fields with a size declared to be larger than the packet size of the client. If you're not getting results try casting all your fields to `varchar(10)` and see if that gets the query working.

Comment: Probably not the issue, but shouldn't you be calling `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` in a loop of some kind?

Comment: @TMNT2014 I am not getting an error. I just don't get any result(the page is blank).

Comment: @andrewsi I am just testing to see if I will get a result at this point.

Comment: your page is kind of a mess, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
if($conn) {
    "Connection established.<br />";
}else {
    "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Try this

```
if($conn) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else {
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

and this

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

As

```
    <?php  
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

And this

```
die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
```

as

```
die('Error: '.sqlsrv_errors());
```

This is no good too

```
$record = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
                {
                    echo $record['Surname'];
                    echo '<br />';
                    echo $record['Initials']; 
                    echo '<br />';
                }
```

So

```
while(false !== ($record = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)))
                {
                    echo $record['Surname'];
                    echo '<br />';
                    echo $record['Initials']; 
                    echo '<br />';
                }
```

Or

```
$record = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);

echo $record['Surname'];
echo '<br />';
echo $record['Initials']; 
echo '<br />';
```

Comment: I made all these changes, but no luck. Is it possible that the issue lie in the SQL statement ?

Comment: anything is possible, can you echo out something from the very bottom of the script, that may tell you if there is more problems, also turn on display errors if you haven't already.  that one line of code can save you tons of pain.